# How to draw a rounded rectangle using HTML Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

HTML Canvas provides methods for drawing rectangles, `fillRect()` and `strokeRect()`, but I can't find a method for making rectangles with rounded corners. How can I do that?

Comment: This guy put how to make rounded rectangles (filled, with border...) in a nice method: http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/07/canvas-rounded-corner-rectangles.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856925/62255

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The HTML5 canvas doesn't provide a method to draw a rectangle with rounded corners.

How about using the [`lineTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) and [`arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) methods?

You can also use the [`quadraticCurveTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/quadraticCurveTo) method instead of the [`arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) method.

Comment: For some reason, I seem to be having issues with arcTo in Firefox 3.5 and Opera 10.0. Similar to this site: http://ditchnet.org/canvas/CanvasRoundedCornerExample.html

Comment: arcTo has been fixed in the latest version of FF.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: As of 2022, there is a specification which might be available soon or later. See [Woold answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255512/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-using-html-canvas/68359160#68359160).

Answer (score 438):

Nowadays you can just use [`context.roundRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect). See further details on [Kaiido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68359160/227299)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("rounded-rect").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

// Draw using 5px for border radius on all sides
// stroke it but no fill
ctx.roundRect(5, 5, 50, 50, 5);
ctx.stroke();

// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.roundRect(100, 5, 100, 100, 20);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, top-left clockwise to bottom-left
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.roundRect(300, 5, 200, 100, [50,0,25,0]);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="rounded-rect" width="500" height="200">
  <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```

---

### Old answer for browsers that don't support `roundRect`

###### As of April 10, 2023, All major browser support it in their latest releases.

See https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_roundrect

---

I needed the same thing and created a function for it.

```js
/**
 * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.
 * If you omit the last three params, it will draw a rectangle
 * outline with a 5 pixel border radius
 * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
 * @param {Number} x The top left x coordinate
 * @param {Number} y The top left y coordinate
 * @param {Number} width The width of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} height The height of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} [radius = 5] The corner radius; It can also be an object 
 *                 to specify different radii for corners
 * @param {Number} [radius.tl = 0] Top left
 * @param {Number} [radius.tr = 0] Top right
 * @param {Number} [radius.br = 0] Bottom right
 * @param {Number} [radius.bl = 0] Bottom left
 * @param {Boolean} [fill = false] Whether to fill the rectangle.
 * @param {Boolean} [stroke = true] Whether to stroke the rectangle.
 */
function roundRect(
  ctx,
  x,
  y,
  width,
  height,
  radius = 5,
  fill = false,
  stroke = true
) {
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {tl: radius, tr: radius, br: radius, bl: radius};
  } else {
    radius = {...{tl: 0, tr: 0, br: 0, bl: 0}, ...radius};
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.tr, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius.tr);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius.br);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius.br, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius.tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

// Now you can just call
var ctx = document.getElementById("rounded-rect").getContext("2d");
// Draw using default border radius, 
// stroke it but no fill (function's default values)
roundRect(ctx, 5, 5, 50, 50);
// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
roundRect(ctx, 100, 5, 100, 100, 20, true);
// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, others default to 0
roundRect(ctx, 300, 5, 200, 100, {
  tl: 50,
  br: 25
}, true);
```

```html
<canvas id="rounded-rect" width="500" height="200">
  <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```

- Different radii per corner provided by [Corgalore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592676/227299)
- See http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/07/canvas-rounded-corner-rectangles.html
  for further explanation

Comment: Perfect answer... How is this not native to canvas yet?! Thanks.

Comment: the code has a bug, it needs to do stroke AFTER fill, otherwise on small rectangles the fill will overwrite the stroke.

Comment: I dont have the example at hand but I had to modify that order for a case I tested on my code. Its logical, how can it correctly stroke (with smoothing using the rect background color) if you havent yet filled the rect?

Comment: @Juan hey my bad, I noticed the blog post and caught that tidbit after. I meant to undo the edit. Goodjob man +1'd you!

Comment: Zig Mandel is correct: it should be filled and then stroked.  The reason is that if you stroke and then fill then the line width is halved.  Try it with a really thick line width (say, 20) and compare a rounded rectangle which is filled with the background colour to a rounded rectangle which is not filled.  The line width of the filled one will be half of the line width of the not filled one.

Comment: took it as a reference ... saved me! thnaks

Comment: there is a minor issue with it:

the stroke() method draws a line in the middle of where you use it. so if you want to stroke a box with x = 100 and a ctx.lineWidth = 40 for example then the rounded corners will be drawn at x - lineWidth / 2 = 80;

which will offset where you wanted to render it and that can cause problems.

Comment: untested, but something like this:

  var strokeWidth = ctx.lineWidth;
  x = x + Math.floor(strokeWidth / 2);
  y = y + Math.floor(strokeWidth / 2);

in the begining of the function should align it properly and make it draw where you want to.

Comment: Daniel, can you create a test case at jsfiddle or a similar site and I can fix this answer?

Comment: Notice: if you use radius > 0 and negative width or height, you will get modern art (not rectangle)...

Comment: I think you need one more equal sign on this line `if (typeof stroke == 'undefined') {`

Comment: @igobivo Technically you don't. typeof can only return a string, this is a preference issue and not really related to the problem itself. Having said that, I will fix it since it's inconsistent :p

Comment: Fantastic solution, thanks very much. Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raddevus/taczyvdm/27/

Comment: in round corner relate to sides of shape is dirty graphics, can handle that?

Comment: @SAt Hard to tell what you're having problems with. I recommend you ask a new question with details and a running example

Comment: **Firefox does not support it** (yet): https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_roundrect or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect#browser_compatibility

Comment: neither does safari

Comment: roundRect is not supported on iOS safari*

Comment: @Alice [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_roundrect) says it's supported

Comment: The problem with iOS safari is depending on the model of apple device you have you can't update safari past a certain version.  Even on iOS 15 this is not supported https://i.imgur.com/0QjJ5mQ.png Which leads me to conclude that this method is not production-ready quite yet. Especially given firefox doesn't support it across the board.

My 2020 iPad Pro is still using a safari version that doesn't support this method.

Answer (score 144):

I started with @jhoff's solution, but rewrote it to use width/height parameters, and using `arcTo` makes it quite a bit more terse:

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (x, y, w, h, r) {
  if (w < 2 * r) r = w / 2;
  if (h < 2 * r) r = h / 2;
  this.beginPath();
  this.moveTo(x+r, y);
  this.arcTo(x+w, y,   x+w, y+h, r);
  this.arcTo(x+w, y+h, x,   y+h, r);
  this.arcTo(x,   y+h, x,   y,   r);
  this.arcTo(x,   y,   x+w, y,   r);
  this.closePath();
  return this;
}
```

Also returning the context so you can chain a little. E.g.:

```js
ctx.roundRect(35, 10, 225, 110, 20).stroke(); //or .fill() for a filled rect
```

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the Canvas rendering context, except for that good solution.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't control the radius for each corner independently. Not flexible enough. See my solution below.

Comment: This is a centered rectangle, if somebody needs one with its top left corner in `(x,y)`, save the context, add a translation to `(-w/2,-h/2)`, and restore the context.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only one that has worked for me thus far, the others giving me issues when the radius was greater or larger than the height or width. Implemented!

Comment: Note that this solution works to make any polygon have rounded corners.
A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doguleez/g082u6oy/).

Comment: Neat solution, but why are you modifying the prototype. It is tidy I guess, but is it convention or anything?

Comment: @Howzieky why would you wanna try a greater radius than the widt, it's impossible.

Comment: @Doguleez how is it supposed to work for every polygon without being totally rewritten?

Comment: @nessa.gp it is not centered, you probobly misread the top two lines.

Answer (score 35):

Juan, I made a slight improvement to your method to allow for changing each rectangle corner radius individually:

```js
/** 
 * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.  
 * If you omit the last three params, it will draw a rectangle  
 * outline with a 5 pixel border radius  
 * @param {Number} x The top left x coordinate 
 * @param {Number} y The top left y coordinate  
 * @param {Number} width The width of the rectangle  
 * @param {Number} height The height of the rectangle 
 * @param {Object} radius All corner radii. Defaults to 0,0,0,0; 
 * @param {Boolean} fill Whether to fill the rectangle. Defaults to false. 
 * @param {Boolean} stroke Whether to stroke the rectangle. Defaults to true. 
 */
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
    var cornerRadius = { upperLeft: 0, upperRight: 0, lowerLeft: 0, lowerRight: 0 };
    if (typeof stroke == "undefined") {
        stroke = true;
    }
    if (typeof radius === "object") {
        for (var side in radius) {
            cornerRadius[side] = radius[side];
        }
    }

    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(x + cornerRadius.upperLeft, y);
    this.lineTo(x + width - cornerRadius.upperRight, y);
    this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + cornerRadius.upperRight);
    this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - cornerRadius.lowerRight);
    this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - cornerRadius.lowerRight, y + height);
    this.lineTo(x + cornerRadius.lowerLeft, y + height);
    this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - cornerRadius.lowerLeft);
    this.lineTo(x, y + cornerRadius.upperLeft);
    this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + cornerRadius.upperLeft, y);
    this.closePath();
    if (stroke) {
        this.stroke();
    }
    if (fill) {
        this.fill();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "blue";
c.roundRect(50, 100, 50, 100, {upperLeft:10,upperRight:10}, true, true);
```

Comment: This approach provides so much control over the rounded corners. Why is this not the accepted answer>

Comment: @VighneshRaut Probably because this answer copy/pasted the original accepted answer and added rounded corners. I incorporated it into the accepted answer gave credit to this answer. The accepted answer has a live example and the syntax is simpler if you do want all corners with the same radius (which is the most common case). Lastly, this answer suggest modifying the prototype of a native object which is a no-no

Answer (score 27):

Good news everyone!

### [`roundRect(x, y, width, height, radii);`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-roundrect) is now officially part of the Canvas 2D API.

It is exposed on CanvasRenderingContext2D, Path2D and OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D objects.

Its `radii` parameter is either

- a single float, representing the radius to use for all four corners,
- an Array which contains either such a single float,
- or two floats, for the top-left + bottom-right and top-right + bottom-left corners respectively,
- or three floats, for the top-left, top-right + bottom-left and bottom-right respectively,
- or four floats, one per corner,
- OR the same combinations, but with `DOMPointInit` objects (any object with a float `x` and `y` property), representing the x-radius and y-radius of each corner and allowing to use arcs of ellipse instead of "just" arcs of circle.

It is now supported in every main browser, and, for older browsers, you can find a polyfill I made in [this repo](https://github.com/Kaiido/roundRect).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.roundRect(20,20,80,80,[new DOMPoint(60,80), new DOMPoint(110,100)]);
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();

const path = new Path2D();
path.roundRect(120,30,60,90,[0,25,new DOMPoint(60,80), new DOMPoint(110,100)]);
ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
ctx.fill(path);

// and a simple one
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.roundRect(200,20,80,80,[10]);
ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/roundRect@main/roundRect.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: is this ever gonna happen?

Comment: @swisswiss it did happen already. It's part of the specs, Chrome has (partial) support.

Comment: @Kaiido i cannot find in which version of chrome is this supported, is not even in documented in MDN

Comment: @CodingEdgar ah, it seems they still do hide it under the Experimental Web Platform flag. For MDN, it's ready to be uploaded at https://github.com/fserb/canvas2D/pull/18/files#diff-cb4343e566a25a1b9180e945317acd744715cf048961b61434d375198bfb58e3

Comment: Firefox does not support it as in the last day of 2022.

Comment: @JayWong yes it's in the answer: "Currently, only Chrome has an implementation available, but you can find a polyfill I made, in [this repo](https://github.com/Kaiido/roundRect).". I will update it when browsers support changes.

Answer (score 16):

The `drawPolygon` function below can be used to draw **any** polygon with rounded corners.

[See it running here.](http://jsfiddle.net/moraes/6ja7Y/4/)

```js
function drawPolygon(ctx, pts, radius) {
  if (radius > 0) {
    pts = getRoundedPoints(pts, radius);
  }
  var i, pt, len = pts.length;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    pt = pts[i];
    if (i == 0) {          
      ctx.moveTo(pt[0], pt[1]);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(pt[0], pt[1]);
    }
    if (radius > 0) {
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(pt[2], pt[3], pt[4], pt[5]);
    }
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}

function getRoundedPoints(pts, radius) {
  var i1, i2, i3, p1, p2, p3, prevPt, nextPt,
      len = pts.length,
      res = new Array(len);
  for (i2 = 0; i2 < len; i2++) {
    i1 = i2-1;
    i3 = i2+1;
    if (i1 < 0) {
      i1 = len - 1;
    }
    if (i3 == len) {
      i3 = 0;
    }
    p1 = pts[i1];
    p2 = pts[i2];
    p3 = pts[i3];
    prevPt = getRoundedPoint(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1], radius, false);
    nextPt = getRoundedPoint(p2[0], p2[1], p3[0], p3[1], radius, true);
    res[i2] = [prevPt[0], prevPt[1], p2[0], p2[1], nextPt[0], nextPt[1]];
  }
  return res;
};

function getRoundedPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, first) {
  var total = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)),
      idx = first ? radius / total : (total - radius) / total;
  return [x1 + (idx * (x2 - x1)), y1 + (idx * (y2 - y1))];
};
```

The function receives an array with the polygon points, like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

drawPolygon(ctx, [[20,   20],
                  [120,  20],
                  [120, 120],
                  [ 20, 120]], 10);
ctx.stroke();
```

This is a port and a more generic version of a solution posted [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128705/WPF-rounded-corners-polygon).

Answer (score 16):

This code creates a 100-pixel square, with rounded corners of 30 pixels.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.arcTo(0,100,0,0,30);
ctx.arcTo(0,0,100,0,30);
ctx.arcTo(100,0,100,100,30);
ctx.arcTo(100,100,0,100,30);
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Finally a brief and comprehensive reply that actually works. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here's one I wrote... uses arcs instead of quadratic curves for better control over radius. Also, it leaves the stroking and filling up to you

```js
/* Canvas 2d context - roundRect
 *
 * Accepts 5 parameters:
     the start_x, 
     start_y points, 
     the end_x,
     end_y points, 
     the radius of the corners
 * 
 * No return value
 */

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function(sx,sy,ex,ey,r) {
    var r2d = Math.PI/180;
    if( ( ex - sx ) - ( 2 * r ) < 0 ) { r = ( ( ex - sx ) / 2 ); } //ensure that the radius isn't too large for x
    if( ( ey - sy ) - ( 2 * r ) < 0 ) { r = ( ( ey - sy ) / 2 ); } //ensure that the radius isn't too large for y
    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(sx+r,sy);
    this.lineTo(ex-r,sy);
    this.arc(ex-r,sy+r,r,r2d*270,r2d*360,false);
    this.lineTo(ex,ey-r);
    this.arc(ex-r,ey-r,r,r2d*0,r2d*90,false);
    this.lineTo(sx+r,ey);
    this.arc(sx+r,ey-r,r,r2d*90,r2d*180,false);
    this.lineTo(sx,sy+r);
    this.arc(sx+r,sy+r,r,r2d*180,r2d*270,false);
    this.closePath();
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
var _e = document.getElementById('#my_canvas');
var _cxt = _e.getContext("2d");
_cxt.roundRect(35,10,260,120,20);
_cxt.strokeStyle = "#000";
_cxt.stroke();
```

Comment: How does this give you better control over radius? I thought you were going to allow for x/y radii (oval corners), and also specifying different radii for each corner

Comment: Your `r2d` probably wants to be called `d2r`.

Comment: @JuanMendes: The (arc-based) shapes of the rounded corners in this solution are more circular than those of your (quadratic-based) solution.  I think that is what he meant by "better control over radius".

Comment: I also used this method, it is better than using quadraticCurve. But if you draw something more complex than rectangle it is REALLY painful. With there was an automatic method like in Android canvas.

Answer (score 11):

So this is based out of using lineJoin="round" and with the proper proportions, mathematics and logic I have been able to make this function, this is not perfect but hope it helps. If you want to make each corner have a different radius take a look at: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect

Here ya go:

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (x,y,width,height,radius) {
    radius = Math.min(Math.max(width-1,1),Math.max(height-1,1),radius);
    var rectX = x;
    var rectY = y;
    var rectWidth = width;
    var rectHeight = height;
    var cornerRadius = radius;

    this.lineJoin = "round";
    this.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
    this.strokeRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
    this.fillRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
    this.stroke();
    this.fill();
}
```

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (x,y,width,height,radius) {
    radius = Math.min(Math.max(width-1,1),Math.max(height-1,1),radius);
    var rectX = x;
    var rectY = y;
    var rectWidth = width;
    var rectHeight = height;
    var cornerRadius = radius;

    this.lineJoin = "round";
    this.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
    this.strokeRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
    this.fillRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
    this.stroke();
    this.fill();
}
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function yop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000)
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";  ctx.roundRect(Number(document.getElementById("myRange1").value),Number(document.getElementById("myRange2").value),Number(document.getElementById("myRange3").value),Number(document.getElementById("myRange4").value),Number(document.getElementById("myRange5").value));
requestAnimationFrame(yop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(yop);
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="10" class="slider" id="myRange1"><input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="10" class="slider" id="myRange2"><input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="200" class="slider" id="myRange3"><input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="100" class="slider" id="myRange4"><input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange5">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since this code may solve the problem, it's better if you add more explanation about how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Opera, ffs.

```js
if (window["CanvasRenderingContext2D"]) {
    /** @expose */
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function(x, y, w, h, r) {
        if (w < 2*r) r = w/2;
        if (h < 2*r) r = h/2;
        this.beginPath();
        if (r < 1) {
            this.rect(x, y, w, h);
        } else {
            if (window["opera"]) {
                this.moveTo(x+r, y);
                this.arcTo(x+r, y, x, y+r, r);
                this.lineTo(x, y+h-r);
                this.arcTo(x, y+h-r, x+r, y+h, r);
                this.lineTo(x+w-r, y+h);
                this.arcTo(x+w-r, y+h, x+w, y+h-r, r);
                this.lineTo(x+w, y+r);
                this.arcTo(x+w, y+r, x+w-r, y, r);
            } else {
                this.moveTo(x+r, y);
                this.arcTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+h, r);
                this.arcTo(x+w, y+h, x, y+h, r);
                this.arcTo(x, y+h, x, y, r);
                this.arcTo(x, y, x+w, y, r);
            }
        }
        this.closePath();
    };
    /** @expose */
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillRoundRect = function(x, y, w, h, r) {
        this.roundRect(x, y, w, h, r);
        this.fill();
    };
    /** @expose */
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.strokeRoundRect = function(x, y, w, h, r) {
        this.roundRect(x, y, w, h, r);
        this.stroke();
    };
}
```

Since Opera is going WebKit, this should also remain valid in the legacy case.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the [`lineJoin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineJoin) property to round the corners. It works if you just need a solid shape, but not so much if you need a thin border that's smaller than the border radius.

```js
function roundedRect(ctx, options) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = options.color;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = options.radius;

    ctx.strokeRect(
        options.x+(options.radius*.5),
        options.y+(options.radius*.5),
        options.width-options.radius,
        options.height-options.radius
    );

    ctx.fillRect(
        options.x+(options.radius*.5),
        options.y+(options.radius*.5),
        options.width-options.radius,
        options.height-options.radius
    );

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

roundedRect(ctx, {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    radius: 35,
    color: "red"
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

To make the function more consistent with the normal means of using a canvas context, the canvas context class can be extended to include a '`fillRoundedRect`' method -- that can be called in the same way `fillRect` is called:

```js
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
var cctx = canv.getContext("2d");

// If thie canvasContext class doesn't have  a fillRoundedRect, extend it now
if (!cctx.constructor.prototype.fillRoundedRect) {
  // Extend the canvaseContext class with a fillRoundedRect method
  cctx.constructor.prototype.fillRoundedRect = 
    function (xx,yy, ww,hh, rad, fill, stroke) {
      if (typeof(rad) == "undefined") rad = 5;
      this.beginPath();
      this.moveTo(xx+rad, yy);
      this.arcTo(xx+ww, yy,    xx+ww, yy+hh, rad);
      this.arcTo(xx+ww, yy+hh, xx,    yy+hh, rad);
      this.arcTo(xx,    yy+hh, xx,    yy,    rad);
      this.arcTo(xx,    yy,    xx+ww, yy,    rad);
      if (stroke) this.stroke();  // Default to no stroke
      if (fill || typeof(fill)=="undefined") this.fill();  // Default to fill
  }; // end of fillRoundedRect method
}
```

The code checks to see if the prototype for the constructor for the canvas context object contains a '`fillRoundedRect`' property and adds one -- the first time around.  It is invoked in the same manner as the `fillRect` method:

```js
  ctx.fillStyle = "#eef";  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ddf";
  // ctx.fillRect(10,10, 200,100);
  ctx.fillRoundedRect(10,10, 200,100, 5);
```

The method uses the `arcTo` method as Grumdring did.  In the method, `this` is a reference to the `ctx` object.  The stroke argument defaults to false if undefined.  The fill argument defaults to fill the rectangle if undefined.

(Tested on Firefox, I don't know if all implementations permit extension in this manner.)

Comment: I suggest adding: `rad = Math.min( rad, ww/2, hh/2 );` so that this works with large radii as in @Grumdrig's version.

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1: Using path-drawing methods

The most straightforward method of doing this with HTML Canvas is by using the [path-drawing methods of `ctx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#paths):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function roundedRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctx.closePath();
}

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
roundedRect(ctx, 10, 10, 100, 100, 20);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  <!-- Fallback content -->
</canvas>
```

### Method 2: Using `Path2D`

You can also draw rounded rectangles in HTML Canvas by using the [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) interface:

#### Example 1

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function roundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return new Path2D(`M ${x + radius} ${y} H ${x + width - radius} a ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${radius} ${radius} V ${y + height - radius} a ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${-radius} ${radius} H ${x + radius} a ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${-radius} ${-radius} V ${y + radius} a ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${radius} ${-radius}`);
}

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill(roundedRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  <!-- Fallback content -->
</canvas>
```

#### Example 2

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function roundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  let path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  path.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
  path.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
  path.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
  path.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
  path.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
  path.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
  path.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  path.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  path.closePath();
  return path;
}

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill(roundedRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  <!-- Fallback content -->
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this line , when you want to get rounded corners : ctx.lineCap = "round";

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap). Are you sure this is a usable answer for rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

NONE of the other answers can handle the following 3 cases correctly:

```js
if ((width >= radius x 2) && (height <= radius * 2))
if ((width <= radius x 2) && (height >= radius * 2))
if ((width <= radius x 2) && (height <= radius * 2))
```

If any of these cases happen, you will not get a correctly drawn rectangle

My Solution handles ANY radius and ANY Width and Height dynamically, and should be the default answer

```js
function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
        /*
         * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.
         */
        let w = width;
        let h = height;
        let r = radius;
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.beginPath();
        // Configure the roundedness of the rectangles corners
        if ((w >= r * 2) && (h >= r * 2)) {
            // Handles width and height larger than diameter
            // Keep radius fixed
            ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);  // tr start
            ctx.lineTo(x + w - r, y);  // tr
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r);  //tr
            ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r);  // br
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h);  // br
            ctx.lineTo(x + r, y + h);  // bl
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r);  // bl
            ctx.lineTo(x, y + r);  // tl
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r, y);  // tl
        } else if ((w < r * 2) && (h > r * 2)) {
            // Handles width lower than diameter
            // Radius must dynamically change as half of width
            r = w / 2;
            ctx.moveTo(x + w, y + h - r);  // br start
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h);  // br curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r)  // bl curve
            ctx.lineTo(x, y + r);  // line
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r, y);  // tl
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r);  // tl
            ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r);  // line
        } else if ((w > r * 2) && (h < r * 2)) {
            // Handles height lower than diameter
            // Radius must dynamically change as half of height
            r = h / 2;
            ctx.moveTo(x + w - r, y + h);  // br start
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w, y + r);  // br curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w - r, y);  // tr curve
            ctx.lineTo(x + r, y);  // line between tr tl
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y + r);  // tl curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x + r, y + h);  // bl curve
        } else if ((w < 2 * r) && (h < 2 * r)) {
            // Handles width and height lower than diameter
            ctx.moveTo(x + w / 2, y + h);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h / 2);  // bl curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w / 2, y);  // tr curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y + h / 2);  // tl curve
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x + w / 2, y + h);  // bl curve

        }
        ctx.closePath();
    }
```