# Wrong rectangle size in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, 2d

I'm implementing a color picker. There is problem with the rendering. When I call `c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 80);` the size of that rectangle is 103x42 px instead of 100x80. What is wrong here?

Also, rectangles are antialiased. Do I need offset the position by (0.5, 0.5) to avoid AA? I didn't use any kind of the coordinate system transformations.

```
colorSlider = function($e, color) {
    this._$canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
    this._c = this._$canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    this._color = color || { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
    this._$canvas.width('310px');
    this._$canvas.height('80px');
    $e.append(this._$canvas);
    this._render();
    var me = this;
    this._$canvas.mousedown(function(e) { me._mouseDown.call(me, e) });
    this._$canvas.mouseup(function(e) { me._mouseUp.call(me, e) });
    this._$canvas.mousemove(function(e) { me._mouseMove.call(me, e) });
    this._dragChannel = 0;
}

colorSlider.prototype._pointInRect = function(x, y, rect) {
    return x >= rect.x && x <= rect.x + rect.w && y >= rect.y && y <= rect.y + rect.h;
}

colorSlider.prototype._findTarget = function(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    console.log(x, y, this._rectR);
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectRThumb)) {
        return { target: 1, value: x - this._rectR.x };
    }
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectGThumb)) {
        return { target: 2, value: x - this._rectG.x };
    }
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectBThumb)) {
        return { target: 3, value: x - this._rectB.x };
    }
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectR)) {
        return { target: 4, value: x - this._rectR.x };
    }
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectG)) {
        return { target: 5, value: x - this._rectG.x };
    }
    if (this._pointInRect(x, y, this._rectB)) {
        return { target: 6, value: x - this._rectB.x };
    }
    return null;
}

colorSlider.prototype._mouseDown = function(event) {
    this._dragChannel = 0;
    var target = this._findTarget(event);
    if (target) {
        switch (target.target) {
            case 1:
                this._dragChannel = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                this._dragChannel = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                this._dragChannel = 3;
                break;
            case 4:
                this._color.r = target.value;
                break;
            case 5:
                this._color.g = target.value;
                break;
            case 6:
                this._color.b = target.value;
                break;
        }
        this._render();
    }
};

colorSlider.prototype._mouseUp = function(event) {
    //console.log('mouseUp');
};

colorSlider.prototype._mouseMove = function(event) {
    //console.log('mouseMove', event);
};

colorSlider.prototype.padding = 4;

colorSlider.prototype._render = function() {
    var padding = this.padding;
    var thickness = 16;
    var c = this._c;
    var w = 255;
    var h = this._$canvas.height();

    c.clearRect(0, 0, this._$canvas.width(), this._$canvas.height());

    var gradient = c.createLinearGradient(padding, 0, w, 0);
    c.fillStyle = gradient;

    gradient.addColorStop(0, this.colorToHex({ r: 0, g: this._color.g, b: this._color.b }));
    gradient.addColorStop(1, this.colorToHex({ r: 255, g: this._color.g, b: this._color.b }));
    c.fillRect(padding, padding, w, thickness);
    c.lineWidth = 0;
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 80);
    this._rectR = { x: padding, y: padding, w: w, h: thickness };

    gradient = c.createLinearGradient(padding, 0, w, 0);
    c.fillStyle = gradient;
    gradient.addColorStop(0, this.colorToHex({ r: this._color.r, g: 0, b: this._color.b }));
    gradient.addColorStop(1, this.colorToHex({ r: this._color.r, g: 255, b: this._color.b }));
    c.fillRect(padding, padding + thickness + 2 * padding, w, thickness);
    this._rectG = { x: padding, y: padding + thickness + 2 * padding, w: w, h: thickness };

    gradient = c.createLinearGradient(padding, 0, w, 0);
    c.fillStyle = gradient;
    gradient.addColorStop(0, this.colorToHex({ r: this._color.r, g: this._color.g, b: 0 }));
    gradient.addColorStop(1, this.colorToHex({ r: this._color.r, g: this._color.g, b: 255 }));
    c.fillRect(padding, padding + 2 * (thickness + 2 * padding), w, thickness);
    this._rectB = { x: padding, y: padding + 2 * (thickness + 2 * padding), w: w, h: thickness };

    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.strokeStyle = "#888888";

    this._rectRThumb = { x: padding + this._color.r - 2, y: padding / 2, w: 8, h: 20, r: 2 };
    this.drawRoundedRectangle(c, this._rectRThumb);

    this._rectGThumb = { x: padding + this._color.g - 2, y: padding / 2 + 2 * padding + thickness, w: 8, h: 20, r: 2 };
    this.drawRoundedRectangle(c, this._rectGThumb);

    this._rectBThumb = { x: padding + this._color.b - 2, y: padding / 2 + 2 * (2 * padding + thickness), w: 8, h: 20, r: 2 };
    this.drawRoundedRectangle(c, this._rectBThumb);
};

colorSlider.prototype.colorToHex = function(color) {
    var c = '#'
    + (color.r + 256).toString(16).substr(1, 2)
    + (color.g + 256).toString(16).substr(1, 2)
    + (color.b + 256).toString(16).substr(1, 2);
    console.log(c);
    return c;
};

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255512/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-on-html-canvas
colorSlider.prototype.drawRoundedRectangle = function(c, rect) {
    var x = rect.x;
    var y = rect.y;
    var width = rect.w;
    var height = rect.h;
    var radius = rect.r;
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    c.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    c.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
    c.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
    c.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    c.closePath();
    c.stroke();
    c.fill();
};
```

index.html

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#directionalLight,#ambientLight").each(function() {
        new colorSlider($(this));
    });

});
</script>

<body>
<div>Directional light</div>
<div id="directionalLight"></div>
<div>Ambient light</div>
<div id="ambientLight"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first thing to know is that a `canvas` element has **intrinsic dimensions** = number of pixels in the **inside coordinate space** (set by the `width` and `height` attributes and properties). It also has  **extrinsic dimensions** (`style.width` and `style.height`) which is the number of pixels that the image takes within the webpage. The intrinsic pixels are scaled to fit the extrinsic space.

It's confusing because an `img` also has intrinsic and extrinsic dimensions, but the names of the properties are completely different from `canvas`. If you set `width` and `height` on an image, it's basically the same as setting `style.width` or `style.height`; they both set the **extrinsic dimensions** to scale the image within the page. Meanwhile, you can only get the **intrinsic dimensions** of an `img` using the new `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` (HTML5 browsers only) properties.

If the extrinsic dimensions are not set on both `img` and `canvas`, the image will be laid out at the same size as the intrinsic dimensions (i.e., scale factor would be 1).

Now, when you use jQuery, `$(canvas).width('310px')` is the same as `$(canvas).css('310px')`, which sets the extrinsic dimensions. You have to call `$(canvas).prop('width', 310)` or simply set `canvas.width = 310` to set the intrinsic width.