# Why doesn't canvas work same or what is the difference between these codes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript. And I can't understand why the codes not working the same. this is the canvas :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

```css
#gameScreen {
  background-color:coral;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  }
```

```html
<!--<canvas id = "gameScreen" width= "200" height= "200" style="background-color:coral"></canvas> -->

<canvas id = "gameScreen"></canvas>
```

this is another canvas :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

```css
#gameScreen {
  background-color:coral;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

why the first one is not working as the second one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default canvas size is 300x150, when dimensions set via style (CSS) it only stretches it to that size.

> The first thing to know is that a canvas element has intrinsic
> dimensions = number of pixels in the inside coordinate space (set by
> the width and height attributes and properties). It also has extrinsic
> dimensions (style.width and style.height) which is the number of
> pixels that the image takes within the webpage. The intrinsic pixels
> are scaled to fit the extrinsic space.

Source: [@yonran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287564/2930038)

Here is an example, click on canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

```css
#gameScreen {
  background-color:coral;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
#gameScreen.small
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!--<canvas id = "gameScreen" width= "200" height= "200" style="background-color:coral"></canvas> -->

<canvas id = "gameScreen" onclick="this.classList.toggle('small')"></canvas>
```