# Javascript, CSS, and HTML - text objects that resize based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to web development, and I need to create objects that contain text in a box with rounded edges, as in the image
[image] The size of the border should grow with the size of the text.

I can't use any css libraries or css3 border-radius. Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction? I don't want full working code - I want to figure the details out on my own - but a list of links or subjects to research would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---edit----
I also can't use any css or javascript libraries. I'm doing this for an assignment rather than a real-world scenario - hence the limitations.

Comment: Why can't you use css3?  Are you trying to target a specific browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't use libraries and css3.. you have two options:

1. Slice up images of a rounded rect, put the text within a div and create a bunch of other divs with background set to those images, details can be found [here](http://cssglobe.com/css-sprites-rounded-corners/)
2. Use a canvas refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255512/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-on-html-canvas)

Don't worry, canvas isn't a library, its a part of the Html5 spec (though I don't know if you can use html5) Read more about canvas and how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) and a simple tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial). How to draw text within a canvas is explained [here](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-text.php)

Comment: The canvas stuff is just what I was looking for, I think I've got it working now. Thanks for the great links!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use css or images to achieve the rounded corner look, you can check out [nifty corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html).

Basically it uses javascript to overlay new tags on the corners and use color contrast to get the curve lines.