# QT 5.7 QML quick semi-transparent rectangle, with rounded corners on one side

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols, qt5.7

I want a semi-transparent rectangular shape using Qt Quick QML, but with rounded corners on 1 side only.

This is sort of the shape of the rectangle I want. If it were not see through, I would probably just overlap 2 rectangles, one with rounded corners and one without. However, this doesn't work with transparency, as the overlap becomes darker.

```
     ----------|
   /           |
 /             | 
|              |
|              |
|              |
 \             | 
   \           |   
     ----------|
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is `Canvas`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [clipping](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop) (see [performance docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#clipping)) to cut off the corners of a single rounded rectangle:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        clip: true

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.rightMargin: -radius
            radius: 10
            color: "navajowhite"
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use [layers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer.enabled-prop) to avoid the overlapping transparency issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Item {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        opacity: 0.5
        layer.enabled: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "navajowhite"
            radius: 10
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "navajowhite"
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned by @folibis, you can also use [Canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html), for which there is already a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368118/904422).