# html5 canvas triangle with rounded corners

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to HTML5 Canvas and I'm trying to draw a triangle with rounded corners.

I have tried

```
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
```

but none of them are working.

Here's my code:

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');

ctx.scale(5, 5);
    
var x = 18 / 2;
var y = 0;
var triangleWidth = 18;
var triangleHeight = 8;

// how to round this triangle??
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight);
ctx.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#009688";
ctx.fill();
    
ctx.fillStyle = "#8BC34A";
ctx.fillRect(0, triangleHeight, 9, 126);
ctx.fillStyle = "#CDDC39";
ctx.fillRect(9, triangleHeight, 9, 126);
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 35):

### Rounding corners

An invaluable function I use a lot is rounded polygon. It takes a set of 2D points that describe a polygon's vertices and adds arcs to round the corners.

The problem with rounding corners and keeping within the constraint of the polygons area is that you can not always fit a round corner that has a particular radius.

In these cases you can either ignore the corner and leave it as pointy or, you can reduce the rounding radius to fit the corner as best possible.

The following function will resize the corner rounding radius to fit the corner if the corner is too sharp and the lines from the corner not long enough to get the desired radius in.

**Note** the code has comments that refer to the Maths section below if you want to know what is going on.

#### roundedPoly(ctx, points, radius)

```
// ctx is the context to add the path to
// points is a array of points [{x :?, y: ?},...
// radius is the max rounding radius 
// this creates a closed polygon.
// To draw you must call between 
//    ctx.beginPath();
//    roundedPoly(ctx, points, radius);
//    ctx.stroke();
//    ctx.fill();
// as it only adds a path and does not render. 
function roundedPoly(ctx, points, radiusAll) {
  var i, x, y, len, p1, p2, p3, v1, v2, sinA, sinA90, radDirection, drawDirection, angle, halfAngle, cRadius, lenOut,radius;
  // convert 2 points into vector form, polar form, and normalised 
  var asVec = function(p, pp, v) {
    v.x = pp.x - p.x;
    v.y = pp.y - p.y;
    v.len = Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    v.nx = v.x / v.len;
    v.ny = v.y / v.len;
    v.ang = Math.atan2(v.ny, v.nx);
  }
  radius = radiusAll;
  v1 = {};
  v2 = {};
  len = points.length;
  p1 = points[len - 1];
  // for each point
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    p2 = points[(i) % len];
    p3 = points[(i + 1) % len];
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 1
    asVec(p2, p1, v1);
    asVec(p2, p3, v2);
    sinA = v1.nx * v2.ny - v1.ny * v2.nx;
    sinA90 = v1.nx * v2.nx - v1.ny * -v2.ny;
    angle = Math.asin(sinA < -1 ? -1 : sinA > 1 ? 1 : sinA);
    //-----------------------------------------
    radDirection = 1;
    drawDirection = false;
    if (sinA90 < 0) {
      if (angle < 0) {
        angle = Math.PI + angle;
      } else {
        angle = Math.PI - angle;
        radDirection = -1;
        drawDirection = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (angle > 0) {
        radDirection = -1;
        drawDirection = true;
      }
    }
    if(p2.radius !== undefined){
        radius = p2.radius;
    }else{
        radius = radiusAll;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 2
    halfAngle = angle / 2;
    //-----------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 3
    lenOut = Math.abs(Math.cos(halfAngle) * radius / Math.sin(halfAngle));
    //-----------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Special part A
    if (lenOut > Math.min(v1.len / 2, v2.len / 2)) {
      lenOut = Math.min(v1.len / 2, v2.len / 2);
      cRadius = Math.abs(lenOut * Math.sin(halfAngle) / Math.cos(halfAngle));
    } else {
      cRadius = radius;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 4
    x = p2.x + v2.nx * lenOut;
    y = p2.y + v2.ny * lenOut;
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 5
    x += -v2.ny * cRadius * radDirection;
    y += v2.nx * cRadius * radDirection;
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Part 6
    ctx.arc(x, y, cRadius, v1.ang + Math.PI / 2 * radDirection, v2.ang - Math.PI / 2 * radDirection, drawDirection);
    //-----------------------------------------
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = p3;
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

You may wish to add to each point a radius eg `{x :10,y:10,radius:20}` this will set the max radius for that point. A radius of zero will be no rounding.

#### The maths

The following illistration shows one of two possibilities, the angle to fit is less than 90deg, the other case (greater than 90) just has a few minor calculation differences (see code).
[image: Shows circle in a corner]

The corner is defined by the three points in red **A**, **B**, and **C**. The circle radius is **r** and we need to find the green points **F** the circle center and **D** and **E** which will define the start and end angles of the arc.

First we find the angle between the lines from **B,A** and **B,C** this is done by normalising the vectors for both lines and getting the cross product. <sub>(*Commented as Part 1*)</sub> We also find the angle of line **BC** to the line at 90deg to **BA** as this will help determine which side of the line to put the circle.

Now we have the angle between the lines, we know that half that angle defines the line that the center of the circle will sit **F** but we do not know how far that point is from **B** <sub>(*Commented as Part 2*)</sub>

There are two right triangles **BDF** and **BEF** which are identical. We have the angle at **B** and we know that the side **DF** and **EF** are equal to the radius of the circle **r** thus we can solve the triangle to get the distance to **F** from **B**

For convenience rather than calculate to **F** is solve for **BD** <sub>(*Commented as Part 3*)</sub> as I will move along the line **BC** by that distance <sub>(*Commented as Part 4*)</sub> then turn 90deg and move up to **F** <sub>(*Commented as Part 5*)</sub> This in the process gives the point **D** and moving along the line **BA** to **E**

We use points **D** and **E** and the circle center **F** (in their abstract form) to calculate the start and end angles of the arc. <sub>(*done in the arc function part 6*)</sub>

The rest of the code is concerned with the directions to move along and away from lines and which direction to sweep the arc.

The code section (*special part A*) uses the lengths of both lines **BA** and **BC** and compares them to the distance from **BD** if that distance is greater than half the line length we know the arc can not fit. I then solve the triangles to find the radius **DF** if the line **BD** is half the length of shortest line of **BA** and **BC**

#### Example use.

The snippet is a simple example of the above function in use. Click to add points to the canvas (needs a min of 3 points to create a polygon). You can drag points and see how the corner radius adapts to sharp corners or short lines. More info when snippet is running. To restart rerun the snippet. (there is a lot of extra code that can be ignored)

The corner radius is set to 30.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  button: false,
  drag: false,
  dragStart: false,
  dragEnd: false,
  dragStartX: 0,
  dragStartY: 0
}

function mouseEvents(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY;
  const lb = mouse.button;
  mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  if (lb !== mouse.button) {
    if (mouse.button) {
      mouse.drag = true;
      mouse.dragStart = true;
      mouse.dragStartX = mouse.x;
      mouse.dragStartY = mouse.y;
    } else {
      mouse.drag = false;
      mouse.dragEnd = true;
    }
  }
}
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));

const pointOnLine = {x:0,y:0};
function distFromLines(x,y,minDist){   
  var index = -1;
  const v1 = {};
  const v2 = {};
  const v3 = {};
  const point = P2(x,y);
  eachOf(polygon,(p,i)=>{
    const p1 = polygon[(i + 1) % polygon.length];
    v1.x = p1.x - p.x;
    v1.y = p1.y - p.y;
    v2.x = point.x - p.x;
    v2.y = point.y - p.y;
    const u = (v2.x * v1.x + v2.y * v1.y)/(v1.y * v1.y + v1.x * v1.x);
    if(u >= 0 && u <= 1){
      v3.x = p.x + v1.x * u;
      v3.y = p.y + v1.y * u;
      dist = Math.hypot(v3.y - point.y, v3.x - point.x);
      if(dist < minDist){
        minDist = dist;
        index = i;
        pointOnLine.x = v3.x;
        pointOnLine.y = v3.y;
      }
    }
  })
  return index;
  
}



function roundedPoly(ctx, points, radius) {
  var i, x, y, len, p1, p2, p3, v1, v2, sinA, sinA90, radDirection, drawDirection, angle, halfAngle, cRadius, lenOut;
  var asVec = function(p, pp, v) {
    v.x = pp.x - p.x;
    v.y = pp.y - p.y;
    v.len = Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    v.nx = v.x / v.len;
    v.ny = v.y / v.len;
    v.ang = Math.atan2(v.ny, v.nx);
  }
  v1 = {};
  v2 = {};
  len = points.length;
  p1 = points[len - 1];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    p2 = points[(i) % len];
    p3 = points[(i + 1) % len];
    asVec(p2, p1, v1);
    asVec(p2, p3, v2);
    sinA = v1.nx * v2.ny - v1.ny * v2.nx;
    sinA90 = v1.nx * v2.nx - v1.ny * -v2.ny;
    angle = Math.asin(sinA); // warning you should guard by clampling
                             // to -1 to 1. See function roundedPoly in answer or 
                             // Math.asin(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, sinA)))
    radDirection = 1;
    drawDirection = false;
    if (sinA90 < 0) {
      if (angle < 0) {
        angle = Math.PI + angle;
      } else {
        angle = Math.PI - angle;
        radDirection = -1;
        drawDirection = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (angle > 0) {
        radDirection = -1;
        drawDirection = true;
      }
    }
    halfAngle = angle / 2;
    lenOut = Math.abs(Math.cos(halfAngle) * radius / Math.sin(halfAngle));
    if (lenOut > Math.min(v1.len / 2, v2.len / 2)) {
      lenOut = Math.min(v1.len / 2, v2.len / 2);
      cRadius = Math.abs(lenOut * Math.sin(halfAngle) / Math.cos(halfAngle));
    } else {
      cRadius = radius;
    }
    x = p2.x + v2.nx * lenOut;
    y = p2.y + v2.ny * lenOut;
    x += -v2.ny * cRadius * radDirection;
    y += v2.nx * cRadius * radDirection;
    ctx.arc(x, y, cRadius, v1.ang + Math.PI / 2 * radDirection, v2.ang - Math.PI / 2 * radDirection, drawDirection);
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = p3;
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}
const eachOf = (array, callback) => { var i = 0; while (i < array.length && callback(array[i], i++) !== true); };
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y});
const polygon = [];

function findClosestPointIndex(x, y, minDist) {
  var index = -1;
  eachOf(polygon, (p, i) => {
    const dist = Math.hypot(x - p.x, y - p.y);
    if (dist < minDist) {
      minDist = dist;
      index = i;
    }
  });
  return index;
}


// short cut vars 
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var dragPoint;
var globalTime;
var closestIndex = -1;
var closestLineIndex = -1;
var cursor = "default";
const lineDist = 10;
const pointDist = 20;
var toolTip = "";
// main update function
function update(timer) {
  globalTime = timer;
  cursor = "crosshair";
  toolTip = "";
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
  if (w !== innerWidth - 4 || h !== innerHeight - 4) {
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth - 4) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight - 4) / 2;
  } else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }
  if (mouse.drag) {
    if (mouse.dragStart) {
      mouse.dragStart = false;
      closestIndex = findClosestPointIndex(mouse.x,mouse.y, pointDist);
      if(closestIndex === -1){        
        closestLineIndex = distFromLines(mouse.x,mouse.y,lineDist);
        if(closestLineIndex === -1){
          polygon.push(dragPoint = P2(mouse.x, mouse.y));
        }else{
          polygon.splice(closestLineIndex+1,0,dragPoint = P2(mouse.x, mouse.y));
        }
        
      }else{
        dragPoint = polygon[closestIndex];
      }
    }
    dragPoint.x = mouse.x;
    dragPoint.y = mouse.y
    cursor = "none";
  }else{
    closestIndex = findClosestPointIndex(mouse.x,mouse.y, pointDist);
    if(closestIndex === -1){
      closestLineIndex = distFromLines(mouse.x,mouse.y,lineDist);
      if(closestLineIndex > -1){
        toolTip = "Click to cut line and/or drag to move.";
      }
    }else{
      toolTip = "Click drag to move point.";
      closestLineIndex = -1;
    }
  }
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  roundedPoly(ctx, polygon, 30);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  eachOf(polygon, p => ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y) );
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  eachOf(polygon, p => ctx.strokeRect(p.x-2,p.y-2,4,4) );
  if(closestIndex > -1){
     ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
     ctx.lineWidth = 4;
     dragPoint = polygon[closestIndex];
     ctx.strokeRect(dragPoint.x-4,dragPoint.y-4,8,8);
     cursor = "move";
  }else if(closestLineIndex > -1){
     ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
     ctx.lineWidth = 4;
     var p = polygon[closestLineIndex];
     var p1 = polygon[(closestLineIndex + 1) % polygon.length];
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y);
     ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.strokeRect(pointOnLine.x-4,pointOnLine.y-4,8,8);
     cursor = "pointer";     
  
  
  }

  if(toolTip === "" && polygon.length < 3){
    toolTip = "Click to add a corners of a polygon.";
  }
  canvas.title = toolTip;
  canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a heads-up, due to floating point precision `sinA` in part 1 might be assigned a value above or below 1 (`1.0000000000000002` or `1 + Number.EPSILON`).  This will cause the angle to be `NaN` because `Math.asin` only works on numbers between -1 and 1. To fix this, I simply clamped the `sinA` variable between -1 and 1.

Comment: @thejustshapingofletters The listed function `roundedPoly` has the guard in the form of a ternary  `as < -1 ? -1 : a > 1 ? 1 : as` , which at the time was quickest. Recently using min and max to clamp is quicker thus the line would be `angle = Math.asin(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, sinA)));`. Sorry the example snippet is mostly proof of concept (to readers) and a self check of my logic, it is not intended to be the solution to copy. Though I will add a warning as `asin` and `acos` should always be guarded with a clamp -1, 1

Answer (score 8):

I started by using @Blindman67 's answer, which works pretty well for basic static shapes.

I ran into the problem that when using the arc approach, having two points right next to each other is very different than having just one point. With two points next to each other, it won't be rounded, even if that is what your eye would expect. This is extra jarring if you are animating the polygon points.

I fixed this by using Bezier curves instead. IMO this is conceptually a little cleaner as well. I just make each corner with a [quadratic curve](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp) where the control point is where the original corner was. This way, having two points in the same spot is virtually the same as only having one point.

I haven't compared performance but seems like canvas is pretty good at drawing Beziers.

As with @Blindman67 's answer, this doesn't actually draw anything so you will need to call `ctx.beginPath()` before and `ctx.stroke()` after.

```js
/**
 * Draws a polygon with rounded corners 
 * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx The canvas context
 * @param {Array} points A list of `{x, y}` points
 * @radius {number} how much to round the corners
 */
function myRoundPolly(ctx, points, radius) {
    const distance = (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2)

    const lerp = (a, b, x) => a + (b - a) * x

    const lerp2D = (p1, p2, t) => ({
        x: lerp(p1.x, p2.x, t),
        y: lerp(p1.y, p2.y, t)
    })

    const numPoints = points.length

    let corners = []
    for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
        let lastPoint = points[i]
        let thisPoint = points[(i + 1) % numPoints]
        let nextPoint = points[(i + 2) % numPoints]

        let lastEdgeLength = distance(lastPoint, thisPoint)
        let lastOffsetDistance = Math.min(lastEdgeLength / 2, radius)
        let start = lerp2D(
            thisPoint,
            lastPoint,
            lastOffsetDistance / lastEdgeLength
        )

        let nextEdgeLength = distance(nextPoint, thisPoint)
        let nextOffsetDistance = Math.min(nextEdgeLength / 2, radius)
        let end = lerp2D(
            thisPoint,
            nextPoint,
            nextOffsetDistance / nextEdgeLength
        )

        corners.push([start, thisPoint, end])
    }

    ctx.moveTo(corners[0][0].x, corners[0][0].y)
    for (let [start, ctrl, end] of corners) {
        ctx.lineTo(start.x, start.y)
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ctrl.x, ctrl.y, end.x, end.y)
    }

    ctx.closePath()
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the problem you mention and of your solution in that situation?

Answer (score 2):

Styles for joining of lines such as `ctx.lineJoin="round"` apply to the stroke operation on paths  - which is when their width, color, pattern, dash/dotted and similar line style attributes are taken into account.

Line styles do *not* apply to filling the interior of a path.

So to affect line styles a `stroke` operation is needed. In the following adaptation of posted code, I've translated canvas output to see the result without cropping, and stroked the triangle's path but not the rectangles below it:

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');

ctx.scale(5, 5);
ctx.translate( 18, 12);
    
var x = 18 / 2;
var y = 0;
var triangleWidth = 48;
var triangleHeight = 8;

// how to round this triangle??

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight);
ctx.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#009688";
ctx.fill();

// stroke the triangle path.

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.stroke();
    
ctx.fillStyle = "#8BC34A";
ctx.fillRect(0, triangleHeight, 9, 126);
ctx.fillStyle = "#CDDC39";
ctx.fillRect(9, triangleHeight, 9, 126);
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: rounded triangle]

This code has the ability to set exactly how much rounding you want, from zero percent = no rounding, to 100 percent = a circle!

```
function drawRoundedPolygon(  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
                            x: number,
                            y: number,
                            radius: number,
                            rotation: number,
                            cornerPercent: number,
                            shadowBlur: number,
                            color: string,
                            numberOfCorners: number ) {


function getPolygonCorner( index: number, numberOfCorners: number ): number[] {
  const angle = ( index + 0.5 ) * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfCorners
  return [ Math.sin( angle ), Math.cos( angle ) ]
}

function lerp( p1: number[], p2: number[], t: number ): number[] {
  return [ p1[ 0 ] * ( 1 - t ) + p2[ 0 ] * ( t ),
           p1[ 1 ] * ( 1 - t ) + p2[ 1 ] * ( t ) ]
}

ctx.save( )
ctx.translate( x, y )
ctx.scale( radius, radius )
ctx.rotate( rotation * Math.PI / 180 )
ctx.beginPath( )

const corners = []

for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfCorners; i++ )
  corners.push( getPolygonCorner( i, numberOfCorners ) )

for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfCorners; i++ ) {

  const prevCorner = corners[ ( i + 0 ) % numberOfCorners ]
  const thisCorner = corners[ ( i + 1 ) % numberOfCorners ]
  const nextCorner = corners[ ( i + 2 ) % numberOfCorners ]

  const q1 = lerp( thisCorner, prevCorner, cornerPercent / 200 )
  const q2 = lerp( thisCorner, nextCorner, cornerPercent / 200 )

  ctx.lineTo( q1[ 0 ], q1[ 1 ] );
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo( thisCorner[ 0 ], thisCorner[ 1 ], q2[ 0 ], q2[ 1 ] ) 
}

ctx.closePath( );
ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur
ctx.shadowColor = color
ctx.shadowOffsetX = ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0
ctx.fillStyle = color
ctx.fill( );
ctx.restore( )
```

}