# Rounded corners on Canvas trapezoid shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a shape using canvas and I am pretty close from what I want. Just the round corners are a bit hard to achieve what I need.

I have the following code

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

// Set rectangle and corner values
var cornerRadius = 5;

// Set faux rounded corners
context.lineJoin = "round";
context.lineWidth = 50;

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(400, 60);
context.lineTo(360, 140);
context.lineTo(240, 135);
context.lineTo(180, 60);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

which result in this shape here
[image: shape]

What I am trying to achieve is having both left and right bottom corners rounded but not the top ones.

If I remove the lineJoin, then the rounded corners are gone.

So, how can I set the points where the lineJoin should run ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do it may be easier to use the `context.drawImage` function.

Comment: @luekbaja i don't think its an option for now as I intend to convert it into a reusable component in future.

Comment: This answer shows how to add rounded corned https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856925/3877726 to any polygon, includes the code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out using [quadraticCurveTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/quadraticCurveTo) that's what I used in this example here. Unfortunately you can't change the join type mid shape, however you have the ability to actually draw the path rounded instead.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 800;

// Set rectangle and corner values
const cornerRadius = 1;

ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(180, 60);
ctx.lineTo(400, 60);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(400, 60, 400, 60);
ctx.lineTo(360, 140 - cornerRadius);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(360, 140, 360 - cornerRadius, 140);
ctx.lineTo(240 + cornerRadius, 135);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(240, 135, 240, 135 - cornerRadius);
ctx.lineTo(180, 60);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```