# How do I round off the corners of a arras client minimap?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, game-development, arras

I just came back after a long time of not coding in arras and what i've always wanted to know how to round off the minimap corners.

[look at this screenshot (sorry for youtube ui)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx5Aa.png)

i have seen this in many servers and i have always wanted to add it to mine. I have tried modifying `linecap` and `linejoin` in canvas as this is what arras runs on. i have changed most of them to `round` and nothing happened.

I am not sure what code i should give. Here is a link to my project as the original best client template is deleted for some reason.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ijkl

***IMPORTANT! LOOK AT BUNDLE.JS please!***

UPDATE: I am going to be looking at arras server too, you can look there if you want but I think it is more likely to be in the client.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/qprxtver

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```js
// Now you can just call
var ctx = document.getElementById("rounded-rect").getContext("2d");
// Draw using default border radius, 
// stroke it but no fill (function's default values)
roundRect(ctx, 5, 5, 50, 50);
// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
roundRect(ctx, 100, 5, 100, 100, 20, true);
// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, others default to 0
roundRect(ctx, 300, 5, 200, 100, {
  tl: 50,
  br: 25
}, true);

/**
 * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.
 * If you omit the last three params, it will draw a rectangle
 * outline with a 5 pixel border radius
 * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
 * @param {Number} x The top left x coordinate
 * @param {Number} y The top left y coordinate
 * @param {Number} width The width of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} height The height of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} [radius = 5] The corner radius; It can also be an object 
 *                 to specify different radii for corners
 * @param {Number} [radius.tl = 0] Top left
 * @param {Number} [radius.tr = 0] Top right
 * @param {Number} [radius.br = 0] Bottom right
 * @param {Number} [radius.bl = 0] Bottom left
 * @param {Boolean} [fill = false] Whether to fill the rectangle.
 * @param {Boolean} [stroke = true] Whether to stroke the rectangle.
 */
function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
  if (typeof stroke === 'undefined') {
    stroke = true;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'undefined') {
    radius = 5;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {tl: radius, tr: radius, br: radius, bl: radius};
  } else {
    var defaultRadius = {tl: 0, tr: 0, br: 0, bl: 0};
    for (var side in defaultRadius) {
      radius[side] = radius[side] || defaultRadius[side];
    }
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.tr, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius.tr);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius.br);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius.br, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius.tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="rounded-rect" width="500" height="200">
  <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```

The code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368118/15342791

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is great! I will see how to implement this into the code.